# Can I see the responses to requests when capturing requests with Postman?

Tags: postman

I have the proxy supported by Postman running. I'm using this to capture requests from integration tests.
I can see the requests in the history tab, but request details do not include response data, such as http code, response body etc.

If I click send, i.e. repeat the request with Postman, then this data is displayed.

I'm really confused here, since Postman is the proxy and is able to capture the request and response both, why on earth it won't bother displaying the response data, and only display details of the request?

How do I display the response to captured requests from another process??

To provide further details: I'm using the proxy, not the interceptor because I'm making calls to localhost and interceptor won't capture those.

Here is what the UI looks like, with the giant question mark showing the empty response section :)
The entries in the history tab are generated by integration tests making calls to a development server running on localhost.

If I repeat the particular (currently selected) request by clicking the send button, it'll display the json response happily.

[image]

Postman is the latest version (as of the date and time of this post) running under WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04

[image]

Comment: Can you provide images of what you can 'see' please. 

Comment: Is it the interceptor that you have set up to capture the requests in history? Which version of the app is this?

Comment: @DannyDainton no, as I indicated in the question, it is not the interceptor, because interceptor does not work with requests made to localhost urls. a proxy which is explicitly configured for the client software is needed. This is the latest postman at v7.34.0

Comment: The question is a little all over the place so it was easily missed. If you're not making these requests through the app or using the interceptor, It wouldn't have that response data in there. A static screenshot of what looks like a request that hasn't been sent doesn't really give us a lot to go on here. Can you walk through your process of getting that data in the history?

Comment: @DannyDainton I'm confused. Don't get me wrong but the Q looks pretty clear to me. I have code written in Java, which uses postman as the proxy, when making calls to http://localhost/api These calls appear in history as java tests run, but only the data related to request is available when I click on the calls in history tab. So postman is 'capturing' only the requests to REST endpoints, but not the response from the server, even though it is the proxy sitting in the middle, which makes it useless for capture, when it captures only half of a req/response sequence of events.

Comment: The question would look perfectly clear, to the person who wrote it :D Even our exchanges has exposed more of the finer details about what you're doing that the original questions didn't mention. So currently we do not capture response either from Proxy or Interceptor. We only capture requests in History tab or any collection. Are you sure Postman is the right tool for this?  Would a more focussed proxy tool, something like fiddler, burp suite or Charles Proxy be better here?

Comment: thanks for the clarification, would you like to write your latest comment as the answer, i.e. response is not captured? I can then accept it as the answer. I went with Charles indeed. fiddler on linux is too problematic unfortunately, especially with the recent versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 8.9, Postman now [allows](https://blog.postman.com/capture-responses-using-the-postman-proxy/) you to capture responses along with requests.